# How is the limit infimum of sets different from the limit infimum of a sequence of real numbers?

Tags: probability, limits, supremum-and-infimum

I am trying to understand whether the limit infimum of a set is related or a generalization of the limit infimum of a sequence of real numbers. Suppose that $X_n$ is a sequence of sets, and so the limit infimum of $X_n$ is defined as **saying that from some stage onwards, all of the $X_n$ occur**.

Concretely:

$$
\liminf_{n \to \infty}X_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k\geq n}X_k
$$

Now, suppose that we let $X_n(\omega) = (-1)^n$ and let $X(\omega) = 1$. Then, we have that:

$$
\liminf_{n \to \infty}X_n = -1
$$

Here it appears that after some time, only $-1$ occurs. But, I know that both $1$ and $-1$ alternate, and so there shouldn't be a time after which $-1$ only occurs.

I am wondering if I am somehow confusing something here between the limit of sets and the limit of a sequence? It also seems that the definition of the limit infimum/supremum of sets has no direct connection to that of a sequence and is an arbitrary definition. Am I wrong here?

Comment: Sorry, what's $\omega$?

Comment: @Brian M. Scott may be helpful here

Comment: @yo' The other post mentions limsups. I am sure you will be able to explain how to transpose these explanations to liminfs.

Comment: @yo' While we are exchanging views, please explain how you came to post an answer defining the liminf as a limsup. Did you check **any reference at all** on the subject before posting?

Comment: after re-reading your comments and the other thread, I see my points are useless. I just wonder whether the OP will be satisfied with the other thread... Howgh.